# How to attach an invite to mail?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

I have registered my app with Microsoft Authorization server and done the process till I get the access token as given in document.
What I am really looking forward is just steps to create an event and send it to user's mail.

I have the access token for my app.
Steps I Know,but dont know whether they are right:
Create a Calendar
Create an event
Insert an event into calendar
and add that calendar to mail.

> The code is same as given in documentation till get access token.

I expect an invite so that user can perform action on it.

*What I need to do sending the mail with invite in java(Spring boot).*
[image]

```
  public class Graph 
{
     private static IGraphServiceClient graphClient = null;
        private static SimpleAuthProvoider authProvider = null;

        private static void ensureGraphClient(String accessToken) {
            if (graphClient == null) {
                // Create the auth provider
                authProvider = new SimpleAuthProvoider(accessToken);

                // Create default logger to only log errors
                DefaultLogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
                logger.setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.ERROR);

                // Build a Graph client
                graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                    .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                    .logger(logger)
                    .buildClient();
            }
        }
       // @GetMapping(value="/getUserDetails")
        public static String getUser(String accessToken) {
            ensureGraphClient(accessToken);

            // GET /me to get authenticated user
            User me = graphClient
                .me()
                .buildRequest()
                .get();
            System.out.println("This is an user "+me.userPrincipalName);
            return "here we are getting user information";
        }
}
```

In the same way I can also get an user's calendars and create an event also,but I want to send the calendar with that event in mail,so the user can add itself.

Comment: It looks like your question hasn't attracted any answers because your question is not very clear. What is your code?

Comment: @4castle I have updated the question with code,basically it is the code till I get the auth code,ide token and access token,now I want to create an event and send it to some mail and user can then add it to calendar?What I am not getting is part where we create event and add it to calendar and send mail?

Comment: @4castle instead of doing this,now I am just creating an ics file and sending it with mail:)

Answer (score 0):

Also took look at [iCalendar specification.](https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/) to understand varoius attributes.

```
public static String getCalendarInvite(MailDTO mailDTO) {
    // DTSTART,DTEND field needs a format yyyyMMddT000000 for a full day event,
    // where 000000 defines full day event

    //here DateFormatter of JodaTime Lib is used for date formatting.
    String DTSTART = DateUtils.formatDatesForICSCalendar(mailDTO.getEventStartDate());
    String DTEND = DateUtils.formatDatesForICSCalendar(mailDTO.getEventEndDate());

    // generating random number,so that UID of calendar object will always be
    // different.
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer buffer = sb.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n"
            + "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN\\n" + "VERSION:2.0\n" + "METHOD:REQUEST\n"
            + "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" + "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:"
            + mailDTO.getAttendeeMail() + "\n" + "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:" + mail.getOrganizerMail()
            + "\n" + "DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:" + DTSTART + "\n" + "DTEND;TZID=Asia/Calcutta:" + DTEND + "\n"
            + "LOCATION:" + mairDTO.getLocation() + "\n" + "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" + "SEQUENCE:0\n" + "UID:"
            + randomUUIDString + "\n" + "DTSTAMP:20180922T120102Z\n" + "CATEGORIES:Interview\n" + "DESCRIPTION:"
            + mailDTO.getDescription() + "\n\n" + "SUMMARY:" + mailDTO.getSummary() + "\n"
            + "PRIORITY:5\n" + "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" + "BEGIN:VALARM\n" + "TRIGGER:PT1440M\n" + "ACTION:DISPLAY\n"
            + "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" + "END:VALARM\n" + "END:VEVENT\n" + "END:VCALENDAR");

    String calendarInvite = buffer.toString();
    return calendarInvite;
}
```